# Can't build my Cordova app for Windows due to a WINJS version error

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, windows, visual-studio-cordova

My visual studio installation worked great and I could build my cordova app for windows (phone and desktop) but now I have the following error after each build (even with a blank cordova app project...):

Error: DEP0700 Windows cannot install package io.cordova.myapp252e6b because this package depends on another package that could not be found. This package requires minimum version 1.0.9600.17018 of framework Microsoft.WinJS.2.0 published by any publisher to install. Provide the framework along with this package. (0x80073cf3)

This is the second time that I have this problem, I solved it by uninstalling then reinstalling visual studio 2015.

This problem appears after I tried a lot of time to build my app to localize the app name with ms-resource in my confix.xml (which didn't work but it's another problem).

How can I solve this problem without reinstalling visual studio?

Thanks by advance for your help.

Comment: A few things. 1. What version of Windows OS are you running?  2. What version of Windows is set as the target in config.xml?  3. If 8.1, can you verify that the "Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.0/8.1 Tools" option is checked by going clicking "Change" and then "Modify" on your VS installation in add/remove programs? 4. Finally, have you recently installed the Windows 10 tools or installed any updates that may have caused this?

Comment: Thanks for your help. 1.Windows 10 2.<preference name="windows-target-version" value="8.1" /> 3.Yes it's checked 4. I have updated the windows 10 tools with the update 3 but I don't think this is linked, i could build my app a lot of time after the upgrade then failed without modification on my side. The first time when I had this problem was with the update 2 of the windows 10 tools.

Comment: Hum my problem seems to be solved...I don't know why but i tried to rebuild my app with the windows x64 simulator and it works. Now it works also on my local desktop, I didn't touch anything and i had this problem since two weeks...

Comment: Glad to hear the problem resolved itself! Hopefully the problem does not recur!